# how to deal with URLs containing lot of spammy keywords?

Tags: google, url, seo, query-string

I'm writing a big index of documents and I'm dealing with URLs

as example I will use the car industry:

somesite.com/manifacturer-mazda_model-miata_engine-1600cc_gas_color-red_hard-top-spider_[[A LOT MORE]].htm

this url points to a generated content that can't be identified as a single resource (in practice, every keyword is a filter and the page result is generated by a database search)

at Google's eyes an URL like this looks spammy or I can use this solution with freedom?

using querystring instead of URL rewriting can fix risks? and, in this case, keywords will be considered as keyword for SERPs?

thank you in advance,
feel free to correct my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough different content for each result page that should be ok. Google is intelligent enough to know that keywords in URL and in query string is the same (but by using Google Webmaster Tools, you can filter query string only).

In your case, those are categorized pages, so that's ok.

About keywords in URL (or as query string): IMHO we don't need them. Google recognises them, but if we put them in a meta tag, Google recognises them, too, and we don't need to put all in URL, just 3-4 are ok.

Comment: the content is not always "so different". every keyword is a filter, and the page content are link lists... so maybe numeric querystrings are better? ty

Comment: I know there are many cars with the same properties, and SERPs of those keywords share the result, but that's not a problem, as there is coherence between URL and the page content. So keywords in query  string is ok (I'm not against it). But again, IMHO, 1/ if those keywords are in meta tags, I think you can make URL shorter (short URLs have a few advantages) by using numeric id instead of keywords. 2/ You can put some main/hierarchical keywords in the URL, like example.com/mazda/miata/?123-45-53-231-814-12

Comment: ok! thank you i will do as you are suggesting, more comments are welcome people!